# Change all filenames in directory to numerals

Tags: files

I have files in a directory where filenames are like

```
01 ABC DEF.m4a
02 DEF ABC.m4a
etc...
```

I want to convert these to

```
1.m4a
2.m4a
etc...
```

How can I do this using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the perl version of `rename` (sometimes called `prename`) you can use this

```
rename -n 's/^0*(\d+).*(\.m4a)\z/$1$2/s' [0-9]*.m4a
```

When you're happy it's going to do what you want, remove the `-n` flag.

This uses a Regular Expression match:

- `^` - require start-of-subject
- `0*` - match zero or more "0"
- `(\d+)` - match *and remember* one or more decimal digits
- `.*` - match everything until...
- `(\.m4a)` - match *and remember*  literal ".m4a"
- `\z` - require end-of-subject¹
- `s` flag - make sure `.` matches any byte (including newline, also valid in file names)

and then uses `$1` and `$2` to reference the value of the bracketed expressions.

---

<sup>¹ Not strictly necessary  here as the file names given by the shell as argument all end in `.m4a` and the previous `.*` is greedy. `$` would also work here, but in `rename` which works on file names (which can be any sequence of non-0 bytes including newline), `\z` is preferable as `$` matches at the end of the subject like `\z` but also *before* an eventual last newline character.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

How for would

```
for FN in *.m4a; do mv -i "$FN" "${FN%% *}.m4a"; done
```

get you?